# MSE and Variance of Bernoulli with probability 2p

Tags: bernoulli-numbers, mean-square-error

A coin $C_1$ has probability $p$ of turning up head and a coin $C_2$ has probability $2p$ of turning up head. All we know is that $0 < p < 1/2$. You are given $20$ tosses. You can choose all tosses from $C_1$ or all tosses from $C_2$ or some tosses from each (the total is $20$). If the objective is to estimate $p$, what do you do?

---

The following is the given solution.

If we choose to have all $n = 20$ tosses from $C_1$, then we get $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ that are i.i.d. $\mathrm{Ber}(p)$. An estimate for $p$ is $\bar{X_n}$ which is unbiased. Hence, MSE over $\bar{X_n}(p)$ is $V[\bar{X_n}] = p(1 − p)/n$.

On the other hand, if we choose to have all $20$ tosses from $C_2$, then
we get $Y_1 , \ldots , Y_n$ that are i.i.d. $\mathrm{Ber}(2p)$. The estimate for $p$ is now $\bar{Y_n}/2$ which is also unbiased and has MSE over $\bar{Y_n}/2(p)$ that is $V[\bar{Y_n}] = 2p(1 − 2p)/4 = p(1 − 2p)/2$.

It is not hard to see that for all $p < 1/2$, MSE of $Y_n(p)/2$ is smaller than MSE of $X_n(p)$ and hence choosing $C_2$ is better, at least by mean-squared criterion.

---

I understood how MSE for $C_1$ is calculated but I couldn't understand how variance of $C_2$ is calculated. Why is it $2p(1-2p)/4$? where does that division by $4$ come from? Can someone help me understand this? Please elaborate the answer as I'm very new to statistics.

Comment: Please improve the mathematical notation with MathJax. What do you mean by " 0 < p < 2 1" ?

Comment: Edited.. I only wanted to know how the variance of C2 is calculated.

Comment: If $Y$ is a random variable with finite mean then $Var(Y/2)=Var(Y)/4$. Can you prove that from the definition of variance? If $Y$ is Bernoulli with $P[Y=1]=2p$ then $Var(Y)=2p(1-2p)$ and $Var(Y/2)$ divides that by $4$.

Answer (score 1):

With some corrections

> On the other hand, if we choose to have all $20$ tosses from $C_2$, then
>   we get $Y_1 , \ldots , Y_n$ that are i.i.d. $\mathrm{Ber}(2p)$. The estimate for $p$ is now $\bar{Y_n}/2$ which is also unbiased and has MSE over $\bar{Y_n}(p)/2$ that is: $$\begin{align}V[\overline{Y_n}/2] ~&=~V[\overline{Y_n}]/4 \\[1ex]~ &= ~2p(1 − 2p)/4n \\[1ex]~&=~ p(1 − 2p)/2n\end{align}$$